# Error 403 on webpage inspite of existing index.html

Tags: html, server

I am trying to setup my own website and I have a folder on my server called public_html which contains my homepage as index.html and other stuff. However, when I try to access this using any browser, I get error 403. Anyone has any idea what is going on?

The file and folder permissions are shown below.
[image]

Comment: ?? Two down votes without even so much as a comment.  How is that helpful to the OP?

Comment: ^ Exactly my question :P

Answer (score 0):

Error 403 is a permissions error.  index.html isn't a binary, so it should work without "x", but try "chmod 744 index.html" (and even 777 BUT ONLY BRIEFLY TO RULE OUT THIS AS THE ISSUE) which would grant all permissions for owner (presumably you) and read only for groups and everyone else.  Read up on it, and experiment with it, but in the end, set the permissions to the lowest level possible that still allows the file to be used as you wish.

From user Krishan Gopal :

```
Number  Octal Permission Representation
0       No permission
1       Execute permission
2       Write permission
3       Execute and write permission: 1 (execute) + 2 (write) = 3
4       Read permission
5       Read and execute permission: 4 (read) + 1 (execute) = 5
6       Read and write permission: 4 (read) + 2 (write) = 6
7       All permissions: 4 (read) + 2 (write) + 1 (execute) = 7
```